# React useEffect does not re-render after sorting entries

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of entries which I want to be sorted according to date at all times. So I incorporated a sorting method in a `useEffect` hook which is supposed to run after a new entry is added.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setEntries(entries.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.date > b.date) {
        return -1;
      }
      else if (a.date < b.date) {
        return -1
      }
      else {
        return 0;
      }
    }));
 }, [entries])
```

Since `entries` is in the dependency array, `useEFfect` should be triggered after a change in entries (entry added). When `useEffect` runs, `setEntries` is invoked, thus the state is changed and I believe it should re-render. Unfortunately this is not happening.

What is going wrong here?

Code for updating the list:

```
function addEntry(date, description, header, amount) {
    if (!date || !description || !header || amount < 0) {
      return;
    }
    setEntries(prev => ([
      {id: Date.now(), date: date, description: description, header: header, amount: amount}, ...prev
    ]))

    setDescription('');
    setHeader('');
    setAmount('');
   }
```

I tried to incorporate the sorting function here at first, but although this function is working, strange enough I cannot access the updated `entries` in the same function after it is updated.

Comment: There are multiple things wrong here. You can't unconditionally set the same state that is triggering the effect. This will lead to an infinite loop, but looks like that is not happening for you. Can you post the code here that is updating the entries list?

Comment: Could you update the question with the formatted code? It's really hard to read this way.

Comment: Yes I put it above now, under the original question

Comment: Posted the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

useEffect doesnt run serially - it runs after the component has been rendered. Infinite loop aside, first the list would render unsorted and then re-render again in a sorted order - doesnt seem like something you'd want?

What you probably are looking for is [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

> useMemo will only recompute the memoized value when one of the dependencies has changed. This optimization helps to avoid expensive calculations on every render.

```
const sortedEntries = useMemo(() => {
    return [...entries].sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.date > b.date) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (a.date < b.date) {
            return -1
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
}, [entries])
```

Comment: Thanks. What exactly is the difference between useEffect and useMemo? I cannot clearly extract that from the React info link.

Answer (score 0):

You mutate you state, also use callback function here:

```
setEntries((prevEntries) => [...prevEntries].sort(...))
```

And it looks like that useEffect initiates infinite loop. Your dependency is entities and you try to modify it inside. It's better to sort entities in function which is responsible for adding new entry

In your case just remove useEffect at all and move sort logic in addEntry function

```
function addEntry(date, description, header, amount) {
    // ...other code
   setEntries(prev => ([
      {id: Date.now(), date, description, header, amount}, 
       ...prev
       ].sort(...your code...)))

     .... other code
  }
```

Comment: Please see my comment on the answer by Zhang TianYu

Comment: I wrote that useEffect initiate infinite loop and another issue is that code mutates state, what the issue?

Answer (score 0):

So like I highlighted in the comments, you shouldn't unconditionally update a state in a `useEffect` where that state is a dependency. Something like this should do the job for you:

```
// after state declarations
const sortedEntries = useMemo(() => entries.sort(...), [entries]);
```

Your handler should update `entries` and not `sortedEntries`. Whenever you update entries, a new sortedEntries will be calculated. Since it is memoized, it won't recalculate when some other unrelated state updates.

Comment: Thanks. Since I am new to React, what exactly is the difference between useEffect and useMemo? They both run once something in the dependency array changes, right?

Comment: Yes. The difference is, useMemo returns the value returned by the function you pass to it. Then on every consecutive render, it returns the same value without running the actual function saving you computation time. It will only re-execute the function you passed to it if a dependency array changes.

Comment: So in your case, if your component re-rendered because some state other than entries was updated, it won't run the sorting function again. It will only re-run sorting when entries is updated

Comment: As Zhang already mentioned, `.sort()` uses in-place sorting - both `sortedEntries` and `entries` would have the same order

Comment: agreed, but in place sorting won't trigger a re-render. We need to make sure that the original list is immutably updated, and then derive a new sorted list from it only when the original list is updated. We could spread out the sorted array in the useMemo callback but that would be unecessary in this case.